# dynamically changing image size in Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, image, resize

I am currently creating a program that dynamically adds Image to a dockPanel every time a user presses a button. I was wondering how I could get it so that every time the user adds another image to the dockPanel the images shrink so that they are both the same size and fit inside the dockPanel.

Here is my current code:

```
 Uri myUri = new Uri(@"C:\Users\Jim\Desktop\Project\bin\Debug\pic.bmp", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            BmpBitmapDecoder decoder2 = new BmpBitmapDecoder(myUri, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
            BitmapSource bitmapSource2 = decoder2.Frames[0];
        // Draw the Image
        Image myImage2 = new Image();
        myImage2.Source = bitmapSource2;
        myImage2.Stretch = Stretch.None;
        myImage2.Margin = new Thickness(20);
        dockPanel1.Children.Add(myImage2);
```

I tried doing `myImage2.Height=80` and `myImage2.Width=40` (thinking that it would change the size through percentage but it didn't seem to work this way.

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Do you **need** to use a canvas or could you use a different layout container?

Comment: @Coding Gorilla sorry I ment to change it to dockPanel. Will make edit

Comment: @Coding Gorilla i'm open to changing it to anything. Only thing about uniformgrid is that its not in my toolbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'd be better served by using a different container, specifically the `UniformGrid` container will do exactly what you want.

Here's a good tutorial: http://www.wpftutorials.com/2011/03/wpf-uniformgrid.html

**UPDATE**

UniformGrid may not be in the toolbox, but it is a built-in primitive so you do have it.

Comment: Awesome yes this is exactly what i needed. Great reference thanks. Any idea why my image isnt fully appearing though? It only shows the top corner of it

Comment: Can you update your question to show the new code?  My guess is that you need to change the `Stretch` property to `Fill` or `UniformToFill`.

Comment: It was the stretch property thanks..i kept trying to mess with the sizes. Thanks soo much for your help!

Comment: Glad I could help, one thing to remember with WPF and it's containers, usually containers will figure out how to arrange and size things for you, so rarely do you need to fiddle with specific sizing.  More often it's a matter of finding the right container to fill your needs.

Answer (score 0):

How to add UniformGrid to your toolbox

```
- In your toolbox, right-click the header "All WPF Controls"

- Click "Choose Items..."

- Select the "WPF Components" tab

- Scroll down to "UniformGrid"

- Click the checkbox so it's checked

- Click "Ok"

- In your toolbox, drag and drop the new UniformGrid control so it's placed in the correct position alphabetically (on mine, it's between "Treeview" and "Viewbox")
```